# Browser does not start in first time in visual studio 2022

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly

I have installed visual studio 2022 with blazor web assembly.When I run this web application in first time the browser does not work,it shows an message **(the site can't be reached)** at the same time when I press control + F5 then the application working fine.please advise how to run the application without control + F5, that means just click run from visual studio 2002

[Browser Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNIo.png)

Comment: Please  help,if anyone face this issues

Comment: Add more details: OS version, Visual Studio version, type of project, .NET version, Browser version, installed tools like .NET WebAssembly build tools.
And you can also report a problem directly to MS. Look how to do it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/